# How can i change my Project quick fix shortcut in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1, keymaps

i work on windows Os.I want to change my default key for Project quick fix in android studio 2.1.Where can i get that and how can i change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio > Preferences > keymap > Other > Show intentions Actions

Comment: sir where in keymap? i am not able to find Project Quick Fix option.

Comment: It is not called "project quick fix", it is called "show intention actions"

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

The keymap under settings is now called "Show Context Actions":
[image: 1]